# In Redis, error message "Invalid argument during startup: unknown conf file parameter : #"

Tags: redis

Steps to reproduce:

1. in windows, Redis in installed
2. opened redis.windows.conf in notepad++
3. modified port number from 6379 to 6377 and save
4. open cmd prompt
5. Enter the following commands

   `cd redis`
     `redis-server.exe redis.windows.conf`

I'm seeing below error message "Invalid argument during startup: unknown conf file parameter :  #"

Comment: perhaps there's a rogue space before some commented out line? check the beginning of the file

Comment: can you paste your config file?

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer that was it! A white space character in front of "bind". Just deleted the hashtag "#" but not the space. Works fine now!